# Praying at school

Tags: quran, source-identification, islamic-scholar

My son is Muslim who goes to a Private Catholic school (they sponsored his visa to the U.S. so he can not leave that school). Is the school allowed to tell him that he can not pray during school hours? How can I advise him during Ramadan when praying is especially important?
Thank you

Comment: Hi, private institutions, including schools, have right to establish rules and regulations within their premises. However, it is essential to ensure that these regulations do not infringe upon an individual's religious rights. But now It is advisable to communicate with school administration to discuss accommodations for religious practices, such as finding a suitable time and place for prayer...